# I recently did an htaccess redirection of php site, The redirect itself works, but now I cannot access the admin panel. All it shows is a blank page

Tags: php, .htaccess, server

I recently did an htaccess redirection of php site, 
The redirect itself works, but now I cannot access the admin panel. All it shows is a blank page.

**Here is the htaccesscode:**

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `.php` file exists before adding it for each request:

```
RewriteEngine On  

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f  
RewriteRule ^(.+?)$ $1.php [L]
```